# Vaadin, slow generation of results

Tags: java, vaadin

I have to generate results of searching i Vaadin.
Probably the fastest way to do it is to put results into table, but I need some custom layout and the FormLayout for every row would be the best.
Unfortunately if I put rows formatted by FormLayout into table - the generation of the results takes about 15-20 seconds.
If i put just some labels/buttons without putting it in a layout the generation takes about a second - and that's fine.

I've read the [vaadin manual](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Optimizing%20Sluggish%20UI) about optimising UI and I still don't know what to do to shorten the time needed to generate the results.

How do you generate results in Vaadin if it can't be presented as a table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is... use CssLayout inside a table. Although CssLayout still consists of 3 div's it's much faster than FormLayout.
I think that using a FlowPanel from GWT would be even better but I didn't have enough time to check it.
And don't forget about setPageLength method of a Table - the lazy loading is the main reason to use a Table :).

Answer (score 0):

Offering a few more layout options:

- [WeeLayout add-on](http://vaadin.com/addon/weelayout): fast layout, not many expensive layout calculations in JavaScript, and a lighter DOM structure than in CssLayout
- [DashLayout add-on](http://vaadin.com/addon/dashlayout): even lighter DOM structure (but more JS calculations), and offers more flexible styling options for CSS (arbitrary margin/border/padding values).